# Quadratic variation of $e^{B_t}$ where $B_t$ is the standard brownian motion.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider $f(x) = e^x$
, then show that $<f(B)>_t$
is equal to
$\int^t_0e^{2B_t}dt$.

1. I know from jensen's inequality that $e^{B_t}$ is a submartingale. How is quadratica variation defined for that? For a square integrable martingale $X_t$ it is the natural increasing process of the D-M decomposition of $X^2_t$
2. Do i somehow have to use ito's formula to get the answer? i tried, but could not get anything.

Comment: For $X_t=e^{B_t}$ you get $dX_t=X_t\,dB_t+\frac12X_tdt$ from the Ito formula. This gives, informally, $(dX_t)^2=X_t^2\,(dB_t)^2=e^{2B_t}\,dt$ for the quadratic variation.

Comment: how to arrive at this informal formula from the integral version of the ito's formula?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in here [Quadratic Variation of Diffusion Process and Geometric Brownian Motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893025/quadratic-variation-of-diffusion-process-and-geometric-brownian-motion), you simply apply Ito's formula to $Y_{t}=f(B_{t})$ get

$$dY_{t}=f'(B_{t})dB_{t}+\frac{1}{2}f''(B_{t})dt=Y_{t}dB_t+\frac{1}{2}Y_{t}dt$$

and so

$$<Y_{t},Y_{t}>=\int^{t} Y_{s}^{2}d[B]_{s}=\int^{t} e^{2B_{s}}ds.$$